# Remove Css class on Mouse Over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jquery function that add a css class "tint" on load. I want to remove this class on hover or when the mouse of over the div.

jQuery:

```
revapi1.on('revolution.slide.onloaded', function () {
    revapi1.find('li').each(function () {
        var slide = jQuery(this);
        if (slide.find('.slidelink').length) {
            slide.find('.slotholder').addClass('tint');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the repavi1 object?

Comment: repavi1 ia the api for the revolution slider i am using

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$( "yourElement" ).hover(function() {
  $( "yourElement" ).removeClass( "tint" )
});
```

Comment: You can place it just after you code, it doesn't interfere with it

Comment: This is just a generic code, put it outside of your code, you are adding tint class on slotholder div, so try replacing "yourElement" with .slotholder

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for removing the class when your mouse moves over the 'element'

```
$("element").mouseover(function(){
    $("element").removeClass("tint");
});
```

You can also use the **hover** function. Moreover there is function called '**toggleclass**' as well incase you want add the class again

```
$("element").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("tint");
 });
```

**Added a slide demo :** 
https://jsfiddle.net/884L0j85/12/